# Access parent fields in a django model's init method

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I want to access the inherited fields of a model from within that models init function -

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_field = models.TextField(default="parent text")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parent_field.default="child text"
```

However when I try and initialize a Child object, `self.parent_field` (in the code above), is already a unicode object rather than a field object.

I know I'm not supposed to be [overriding fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted). I guess I'd need to override something in the meta class. Is there a way of doing this? Or am I just making trouble?

Comment: You can lookup the parent classes and their fields through `__bases__` or `__mro__` but instead of fiddling on instantiation you could look into other techniques, but it really all depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Btw your call to super should usually come _after_ you make changes.

Comment: Thanks @hedde. I'll have a play around. I started on this trying to mess with proxy classes (adding required=True or editable=False). Now I'm just trying to learn a bit more about how models work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing model data with model metadata.
Fields belong to the metadata. They are used at loading & saving data.
The model's properties, on the contrary, are always data. That's why `self.parent_field` is a unicode object. 
To access the field objects, you need to access the model's metadata, namely `self._meta` object (that's where all the stuff from the `class Meta` also goes). The fields are in `self._meta.fields`, which is a list of `django.models.Field` objects defined for the class.

Answer (score 2):

use `_meta.get_field` as below:

```
class Child(Parent)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field('parent_field').default="child text"
```

Answer (score 1):

OK my tested and working code -

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_field = models.TextField(default="parent default")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for f in self._meta.fields:
            if f.attname == "parent_field":
                f.default = "child default"
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks to mderk.

Comment: btw to call `super` at the end you must know what exactly is going on. Some features you rely on may be set only at the parent's constructor. What if self._meta was added in the Model.__init__ ? (not the case, it is added in the `ModelBase` metaclass, but good enough to illustrate).
Calling `super` at the very beginning is much safer.

Comment: Yeah, I think I need to keep reading. The code fails if I put super at the beginning, and I can't seem to tweak certain other field attributes using this method (such as readonly).

Comment: in you particular case, you don't need to call this from the `__init__` (at every instance creation), but just after the class definition (`_meta` is a class' attribute, not the instance's)